# I am trying to dynamicallyload mynavbar content from my django model database without affecting the display page

Tags: python, django

My template structure is **base.html** where i included **navbar.html** inside the base

I have an app called tags and tags has a **models.py** and a **views.py**
inside the **views.py**, i have a django code as this

```
from tags.models import Tag

class TagList(ListView):
    model = Tag

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tags.object.all()
```

this works, when i call *{{ object_list }}* inside my template for the **tag_list.html**.
So i added the *{{ object_list }}* inside my template **navbar.html** which was included inside the **base.html** but it works only when am on the url that displays my **tag_list.html** and does not show anything when am on other urls or other templates..

How do I make it show irrespective of the template directory am inside or the url am displaying ... i want it to show

I've thought of copying my **views.py** code into every app view and repeat the same process for every templates but i have a lot of template directories i cannnot do this for all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this variable for all pages you can use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).
Otherwise a mixin class similar to [ContextMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L16) could also do the job:

```
# views.py
class MyContextMixin:
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags_list'] = Tags.object.all()
        return context

class TagList(MyContextMixin, ListView):
    model = Tag
```

You can then extend each View as follows:

```
# other views.py
from tags.views import MyContextMixin

class OtherView(MyContextMixin, ...):
    ...
```

In both cases you add another `context` variable. Note that I renamed `object_list` to `tags_list` to not override the variable name used by `ListView`.